# Generating your OAuth Linkedin token : Oops. We can’t verify the authenticity of your request because the state parameter was modified

Tags: jwt, token, access-token, linkedin-api

When I try to request access token OAuth 2.0 for a LinkedIn app, I receive the following error:

> Oops. We can’t verify the authenticity of your request because the state parameter was modified.

I run into an issue with using the LinkedIn developer platform. My app uses `r_emailaddress` and `r_liteprofile`

When I try to renew an OAuth 2.0 access token for a LinkedIn app, I receive the following error:

> Oops. We can’t verify the authenticity of your request because the state parameter was modified.

I can't fix the problem after studying the official documentation, so I'm asking for your help.

[image: Error in image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and... apparently it was only because I was on Brave. Works like a charm on Chrome.

Comment: I am receiving the same error on edge as well.

Comment: I had the same problem in Chrome. I got it working in Firefox. The answer seems to be "try a different browser". :-)

Comment: Worked for me on edge

Answer (score 0):

So far I have seen it creates problem when you are already logged in the same browser with Linkedin personal profile and apps dashboard etc.

If you open the  OAuth 2.0 tools link in incognito mode and then try to create a token it creates perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Postman callback URLs `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback` and `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback` to your Redirect URL list.
And remove default redirect URL then run request again, it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it on another browser it works well...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just turn off all browser extensions temporarily